# Как работает Files.move() и быстрое перемещение файлов

Tags: java, io

Столкнулся с задачей, что нужно переместить файл из директории пользователя во временную директорию программы. Для этой задачи было найдено два метода:

1. `File.renameTo()` — стандартный вариант перемещения файлов.
2. `Files.move()` — более новый вариант перемещения файлов.

В документации у первого метода было слишком много "но" и он мог завершиться без результата, но и без ошибки. Поэтому было решено перейти ко второму варианту. На сколько я понял, если файл находится на том же разделе, что и новое место положение, происходит переименование и это занимает секунду.

---

Вопроса, фактически, два:

1. Какой самый устойчивый способ переместить файл на другой раздел и безопасно ли это делать методом `move`?
2. Как этот способ работает "под капотом" (будет ли какое-то специфическое переименование или файл просто скопируется)?

Comment: очень похоже на [XY-проблему](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy). что именно вы хотите? переместить файл наиболее устойчивым способом? изучить реализацию метода `move`? или что-то другое?

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если посмотреть на реализацию метода `move`, то мы увидим следующий код

```
public static Path move(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options)
    throws IOException
{
    FileSystemProvider provider = provider(source);
    if (provider(target) == provider) {
        // same provider
        provider.move(source, target, options);
    } else {
        // different providers
        CopyMoveHelper.moveToForeignTarget(source, target, options);
    }
    return target;
}
```

Как видно из кода есть два варианта:

1. Если перенос осуществляется в пределах одного раздела, то происходит перенос файла
2. Если перенос осуществляется на другой раздел, то происходит копирование файла с последующим удалением исходного

   ```
   /**
    * Simple move implements as copy+delete for use when source and target are
    * associated with different providers
    */
   static void moveToForeignTarget(Path source, Path target,
                                      CopyOption... options) throws IOException
   {
       copyToForeignTarget(source, target, convertMoveToCopyOptions(options));
       Files.delete(source);
   }
   ```

Для обеспечения надежности вы можете использовать ключ **ATOMIC_MOVE** - он гарантирует, что операция перемещения будет произведена атомарно, то есть операция либо выполняется целиком, либо не выполняется вовсе.

Comment: А как именно происходит перемещение в первом случае? Там интерфейс и у меня догадка, что подставляется провайдер конкретной файловой системы.

Comment: да. в первом случае используются функции конкретной ОС. я дополню вопрос одним важным нюансом.

Comment: А разве можно гарантировать атомарность? Что, если выключат свет?

Comment: если выключат свет, то файл не переместиться совсем. и да, гарантировать надежность можно лишь с определенной долей вероятности. но это отдельный вопрос надежности.